# SPI Channel 1 with MCP3002 in Windows 10 IoT

Tags: spi, windows-iot

I am learning SPI with the RPi2 and after the first great test with CH0 now I want to make the following steps, but I have several doubts:

[image: RPI2Pinout]

1. What is the use of the pin 26 [SPI0 CS1]?
   That means that there are ADCs with two channel select signal? Any example?
2. To use the channel 0 I have no issue, but to use the channel 1 I have:

```
return new SpiConnectionSettings(ChipSelect0)
{
    ClockFrequency = 500000,
    Mode = SpiMode.Mode0
};
```

Where ChipSelect == 0. simple.

Do I have to change something in the Writebuffer from:

```
public byte[] WriteBuffer = new byte[2] { 0x68, 0x00 };
```

to another writebuffer to read from the other channel?

Answer (score 2):

Finally digging in to the specifications and testing, to use the channel 1 you need to use

```
new byte[2] {0x70,0x00}.
```

It would be great if someone post the bytes for the MCP3008. At this moment I do not have any so I will test when I get one.

With that can be used to sensors with the SPI0 directly.